# consecutive getElementById, Multiple getElementById in series,how call div in div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code in javascript, where I have

```
actual = document.getElementById("samedivid");
var a = actual.getElementById("anotherdivid");
a.style.display="none";
```

and HTML is

```
 <div class="some" id="samedivid">
    <div id="anotherdivid">something</div>
 </div>
<div id="anotherdivid">something</div>
```

I want to get div in div.
but it's not working

Comment: you cannot use the same ID twice

Comment: and what is the purpose of consecutive getElementById ? ID is unique so you get what you need in one iteration

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. `getElementById` is a method of `document`, and can only be called as `document.getElementById`. Read  this [MDN wiki page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for more information. To save getting down voted in future (you can't go lower than one point) check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)  "how to ask" pages.

Answer (score 0):

DOM IDs should be unique. This is the reason why `getElementById` belongs to document object which searches throughout the entire HTML. You can search a DOM element by unique ID or by classnames.

```
<div class="some" id="samedivid">
    <div class="anotherdivid">something</div>
 </div>
<div class="anotherdivid">something</div>
```

Scripts should be

```
var actual = document.getElementById("samedivid");
var a = actual.getElementsByClassName("anotherdivid")[0];
a.style.display="none";
```